# Visualising a region involving the $1$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm a long-time lurker but first-time poster so I apologise if this post isn't formatted correctly. I'm having trouble visualising the region $\mathcal{R}$ defined as:
$$\mathcal{R}=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2:\Vert{\textbf{x}}\Vert_1\leq\lambda, \lambda>0\}$$
I know that the unit ball for the $1$-norm is a diamond shape, so I thought that $\mathcal{R}$ would be the diamond in the first quadrant (i.e. a triangle with the vertices $(0,0),\ (1,0),\ (0,1)).$ But my lecturer said that $\mathcal{R}$ is a square with the vertices $(0,0),\ (0,1),\ (1,0),\ (1,1).$

I know this problem is trivial but there is obviously a hole in my understanding which I'm hoping you can help me fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: I know that $\Vert{\textbf{x}}\Vert_1=|{x}_1|+|{x}_2|$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, as well as the general definition of the p-norms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a square. Let inspect the unit norm ball.
$$\mathcal{R}=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2:\Vert{\textbf{x}}\Vert_1\leq 1\}$$

Let say, $\Vert{\textbf{x}}\Vert_1= 1.$ So,
$$|x_1|+|x_2|=1.$$
**Case-1** When, $x_1,\ x_2 \geq 0,$ 
$$x_2=1-x_1.$$

**Case-2** When, $x_1 > 0,\ x_2 < 0,$ 
$$x_2=x_1-1.$$

**Case-3** When, $x_2 > 0,\ x_1 < 0,$ 
$$x_2=x_1+1.$$

**Case-4** When, $x_1, \ x_2 < 0,$ 
$$x_2=-(x_1+1).$$

So, now you can draw the region, and you will find that it is a square having vertices $(-1,0),\ (1,0), \ (0,1),\ (0,-1).$

Comment: Ahh, thank you. This region was part of a broader discussion about the double integral of $f(x,y)=1$ bounded by R, so I would assume that he shifted the square considering the area is unchanged. Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You're both wrong!

It's actually the square whose corners are $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,-1)$.